# cmake does not detect ant

Tags: opencv, cmake, ant

when configuring cmake for opencv, cmake does not detected ant. Ant installed with apt. Here is the conclusion cmake:

```
    Detected processor: x86_64
    Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")

    ...

      Java:                          
        ant:                         NO
        JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
        Java wrappers:               NO
        Java tests:                  NO

      Install to:                    /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencvJava
    -----------------------------------------------------------------

    Configuring done
```

followed this [guide](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html).
the file `.bashrc` says:
`export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant`
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
`export ANT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/share/ant/bin`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it!
In Cmake-gui, add entry "ANT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/share/ant/bin/ant"

My result:

```
Java:                          export all functions

  ant:                         /usr/share/ant/bin/ant (ver 1.10.7)
  JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
  Java wrappers:               YES
  Java tests:                  NO
```